Onomatopoeia for a noise people make when shutting someone up?
When someone wants to shut someone else up, they often make a noise that sounds kind of like "up-up-up," or "ah-ah-ah," often while putting a finger to the person's mouth. How exactly would this be spelled if I included it in dialogue?
Since nobody seems to know what I'm talking about, here are the closest examples I could find:
Jurassic Park
Deadpool (1:00)

Often? In my experience (UK) they are more likely to put a finger to their own lips and say "Ssh!" (traditionally written "Hush").

@KateBunting it's like that but more condescending.

Great that you added examples, but where in the Deadpool video is it? Can you add the minute and second?

I did. It's at exactly 1:00

Papa Solen'ya, I recommend that you '@' symbol Ben so that he gets the notification that you mentioned him in you comment. Otherwise, he'll probably never see it. Of course, it only matters if you want to notify him. Good question by the way ;)

I think the phrase might actually be "uh-uh" (repeated) rather than "ah ah". "uh-uh" means "no".  We've always used it as an instruction to our dogs to tell them to stop doing something. (It's also defined with this meaning in the dictionary).

@MZB yes, exactly like with dogs. It's really condescending when done to a person.

There are lots of sounds that are hard to write, but that are understood within a cultural group. For example, if I write "uh oh" I mean something went wrong, or something is bad. But "uh huh" means yes and "uh uh" means no, usually a disagreeing one such as denying an accusation or refusing an instruction. And "unh unnnnh" means the same with a lot of emphasis. Do those syllables mean that to someone from Europe, or even another part of North America than me? Probably not.
Yes, sometimes when I want to stop someone -- not just from talking, but from reaching for something or going somewhere -- I will say something that is kind of like "ah ah ah" or "uh uh uh" or even "a a a" with pauses (I'm not sure I'd say glottal stops exactly) between the syllables. Sometimes, the last syllable is distinctly longer, which makes it maybe ironic? Aware that it's not how peers communicate? Anyway, if I hear that, I know what it means.
But can you depict it in text? Apparently not, looking at the other answers here. You could either lavish a little more attention on it:

"ah ah ah!" chided Susan, stopping Sam mid word. "What is this, kindergarten?" he replied, though he did put his hand back down at his side.

Or you could just have your character say something different like "stop!" or "enough!" or "hsssst!" or something you feel you can reliably transcribe and the reader will know this isn't a shush, this is an authority insisting on something stopping right now.

I don’t think there can be an exact spelling for your specific onomatopoeia because that would suggest it has a correct spelling.
That said, to my ear, the leading ‘h’ sounds off. But, “up up up,” seems really bad. I think that the big challenge with trying to communicate sounds is that everyone has a different ear  —- also regional pronunciations will also play a role in how in readers imagine your onomatopoeia.
I wonder if you would find something you like by associating the sounds you want to describe with some specific words.  I imagining something like
Pat shushed Sam, her finger to his lips. “hop hop hop.” But with her heavy accent is sounded more like a breathy, “upp, upp, upp,” or …

It is definitely not an o sound. More like ah or uh.

Preliminary Considerations
Onomatopoeia can be more or less conventional. Some, like bang, have already acquired word status and their orthography and meaning is fixed. Others, like sh and mm-hmm and its orthographic variants (shhh, shush, etc.), vary within a certain predictable frame (e.g. shosh is not possible for the meaning "be quiet!", but sh-sh is).
When there is no existing convention for the written representation of a certain sound, you are free to find the spelling that to your own ear most accurately represents it. For example, James Joyce invented tattarrattat for (as it is commonly interpreted) someone knocking at a door. The Oxfort English Dictionary does not give a meaning for that onomatopoeia, given the ambivalence of the sentence it appears in:

... messengerboy today I thought it was a putoff first him sending the port and the peaches first and I was just beginning to yawn with nerves thinking he was trying to make a fool of me when I knew his tattarrattat at the door he must have been a  ...

The knocking seems plausible, but we could just as well imagine the "messengerboy" stamping his feet or blowing a trumpet (in fact täterätä is the convention for the sound of trumpet blowing in German, and since Joyce lived in German-speaking Zurich he might have been familiar with this and thought of it when he wrote his novel).
Common onomatopoeia are usually understood by most readers, and yet, due to their imprecise meaning, they are commonly accompanied by some kind of explanation of what they refer to. For example, a bang can refer to different kinds of sudden, loud noises, the source and quality of which might be clear if you heard it, but needs to be specified in writing:

The gun went off with a loud bang.
Bang! He violently slammed the car door.
He banged his fist on the table.

For uncommon onomatopoeia, such as tattarrattat, such an explanation is even more necessary, if you want it to be understood in a specific way and not cause misunderstanding.
Advice for Your Special Case
I have never heard anyone make a sound like hup up up with the meaning "shut up". In fact I have never encountered an onomatopoeia spelled like that or similar to it. I believe that using this sound to shut someone up is an uncommon verbal behavior, maybe limited to a certain region or even to that individual, and that there is no fixed convention for its written representation.
I would therefore try to represent the actual sound as closely as possible using letters and explain the meaning in the surrounding text. How you would spell this will then depend on what sounds the person actually makes. If they say "hup up up" (saying distinct individual "words") then that is how you would spell it. If they say "hup-up-up" (contracting the "words"), then that is how you spell it. If they use different vowels or a longer breathy noise at the beginning, you might write hhhap-ap-ap.
In short:
Write it however you want. But explain what it means.

Edit after your comment.
I believe what you mean is the reduplication of the negation interjection /əɂə​ː/ or /həɂə​ː/, and it would be pronounced /əɂəɂə/ or /əɂəɂə​ː/. So actually what your character is saying is "No, no no!", but using sounds made with a relaxed mouth instead of articulating the word no. It can be said with an open mouth: "a-a-a" /əɂəɂə/, or a closed mouth: "hm-m-m" /hmɂmɂm/. The exact pronounciation of the vowel will vary between /​ʌ/ and /ə/, and a short or long last vowel, depending on the speaker. So /ʌɂʌɂʌ/ and /ʌɂʌɂʌː/ or /əɂəɂʌ​ː/ and so on are possible as well. Here is a video example from Bob's Burgers, 2015, season 5, episode 18, "Eat, Spray, Linda": https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/c26c1818-6c20-4050-b5f5-6981d290721d
I don't believe there is a standardised or conventional orthography for this. It is sometimes written ah ah ah (meaning 1). Personally, I would maybe rather use "a-a-a" or "a-a-ah" instead of "ah ah ah", because the h signifies a long vowel and the first two a's are always short, and because the a's aren't pronounced as separate words but as "one word" (therefore the hyphens). Whichever spelling you use, you need to explain what it means, because, due to the lack of a conventionalised spelling, the meaning won't be readily apparent to your readers.
(For an explanation of the phonetic notation, please refer to this chart.)

It doesn't sound like "words". It's said very fast. It sometimes sounds more like "ah-ah-ah" with a glottal stop between each sound. It's not always consistent, but it's always a central or back open vowel.

@PapaSolen'ya I believe I know what you mean. See the edit at the end of my answer.
